# Emit an event from electron main js into a vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

I am currently building an electron app in electron version 5.0.0

I am using electron's power monitor functionality but this can only beaccess from the main electron js file but I need to let a vue component know. I tried using event bus

```
    powerMonitor.on('lock-screen', () => {
        console.log("locked")
        EventBus.$emit('logout');
    })
})
```

but it looks like evenbus only works within vue components. Anyone got any ideas on how i can just send an even from the electron main js file into a vue component

Answer (score 2):

Okay I finally figured out how its done.

You have to use the ipcRenderer listener wil using webContents to send the event. It should look something like this.

```
//main.js
    powerMonitor.on('unlock-screen', () => {
        console.log("unlocked")
        win.webContents.send('computer-unlock')
    })

//Vue Component
    require('electron').ipcRenderer.on('computer-unlock', () => {
                console.log("logging in");
                _this.computerLocked = false;
    })
```